# plsql conditional where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I'd like to perform a conditional `where` in a sql statement, and use two different criteria, e.g. in pseudo code:

```
procedure(..., bool_value IN boolean default false) is
....
begin

select * from mytable mt
where 
     if bool_value = true then mt.criterion_1 = value
     else
        mt_.criterion_2 = value; -- if boolean value is set, use criterion_1 column, otherwise use criterion_2 column

end
```

Suppose it's possible, What's the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: shree.pat18 and Nishanthi: thanks for your solutions, it works ! As pointed out, testing with Boolean won't work in Oracle, because SQL has no equivalent data type. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/datatypes.htm#LNPLS348

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool_value_string varchar2(5)

bool_value_string = case when bool_value then 'true' else 'false' end;

select * from mytable mt
where 
(bool_value_string = 'true' and mt.criterion_1 = value)
or
(bool_value_string = 'false' and mt.criterion_2 = value)
```

Basically, convert your when...then idiom to an either...or one. Either the boolean field is non-null and true, meaning filter has to be by the first criterion, or it isn't, meaning filter by the second one.

Comment: Unless something has changed very recently in Oracle, `bool_value = true` doesn't work; you can't use boolean variables in an SQL statement.

Comment: @ammoQ This was meant to be pseudo-code, but you are right in pointing out the issue with booleans. I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @ammoQ yes double thanks for pointing that out. Will stick as far clear of Oracle as possible now I know that.

Comment: `bool_value is null` also doesn't work ` PLS-382: expression is of wrong type`. You have to keep your boolean variables totally out of the SQL statements.

Comment: @ammoQ Damn forgot to remove that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, your condition gets translated as:

```
 if bool_value = true 
       then mt.criterion_1 = value
 else if bool_value = false
       then mt_.criterion_2 = value;
```

Since you cannot directly use boolean value in select statements (Refer comments), use as below: (Change bool_value from boolean to varchar2 or a number)

```
procedure(..., bool_value IN varchar2(10) default 'FALSE') is
....
begin

   select * from mytable mt
    where  
      (case 
          when (bool_value = 'TRUE' and mt.criterion_1 = value) then (1)
          when (bool_value = 'FALSE' and mt_.criterion_2 = value) then (1)
          (else 0)
      end) = 1;

OR

      select * from mytable mt
      where 
      (bool_value = 'TRUE' and mt.criterion_1 = value)
       or
      (bool_value = 'FALSE' and mt.criterion_2 = value)


end
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can also use `case statement` in `where` clause as below:

```
select * from mytable mt
where  
  (case 
      when (bool_value = true and mt.criterion_1 = value) then (1)
      when (bool_value = false and mt_.criterion_2 = value) then (1)
      (else 0)
  end) = 1;
```

In oracle, you can use below Query also.

```
  select * from mytable mt
  where 
  (bool_value = true and mt.criterion_1 = value)
   or
  (bool_value = false and mt.criterion_2 = value)
```

Note: Since default of `bool_value = false`, `is null` condition need not be checked.

Comment: You can't use boolean variables or literals `true`, `false` in an Oracle SQL statement.

Comment: @ammoQ and carmellose: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465405/how-to-use-boolean-type-in-select-statement>

Answer (score 1):

Simplest form is this:

```
WHERE (bool_value = TRUE AND mt.criterion_1 = value)
OR (bool_value = FALSE AND mt.criterion_2 = value)
```

Comment: As already mentioned by ammoQ in response to shree.pat18's answer, this won't work, since Oracle doesn't support Booleans in SQL.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt as already mentioned by shree.pat18, the answer was intended to be pseudo code as we did not know what data type the bool_value actually was.