# How to convert Boolean to Number in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a boolean value and I am trying to convert it to number in PL/SQL.

```
PROCEDURE Test(
   contract_ IN VARCHAR2,
   mch_code_ IN BOOLEAN)   
IS
  val_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  val_ := mch_code_.to_number();
...some code
END Test;
```

This is not working.

How to convert to number from boolean in PL/SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465405/how-to-use-boolean-type-in-select-statement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `case`:

```
create PROCEDURE Test(
   contract_ IN VARCHAR2,
   mch_code_ IN BOOLEAN)   
IS
 val_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  val_ := case when mch_code_ then 1 else 0 end;
...some code
END Test;
```

Comment: Actually the `case` should preserve `NULL` and not assume that NULL is FALSE: `case when mch_code_ then 1 when NOT mch_code_ then 0 end`

Comment: Hi, i tried this code in the select. But can't work :). why plsql can't support bool?

Comment: @Oğuz: PL/SQL supports boolean, but Oracle's SQL does not

Answer (score 8):

> How to convert to number from boolean in plsql?

You need to use `sys.diutil.bool_to_int` to convert a boolean to a number. See below demo.

```
DECLARE

  var BOOLEAN :=TRUE;
  var1 varchar2(10);
BEGIN 
  --Converting boolean to int here and checking.
  var1:=CASE WHEN (sys.diutil.bool_to_int(var)) = 1 THEN 'TRUE'
             WHEN (sys.diutil.bool_to_int(var)) = 0 THEN  'FALSE'
             END;  
    dbms_output.put_line(var1);
END;
```

Output:

```
anonymous block completed
```

In your case it becomes like:

```
PROCEDURE Test(
        contract_ IN VARCHAR2,
        mch_code_ IN BOOLEAN)
IS
    val_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
    val_ := sys.diutil.bool_to_int(mch_code_);
    ...SOME code
END Test;
```

Comment: do we really need to use this function? Case will be the better option here correct?

Comment: @Gaj that's already shared by horse. I cannot post duplicate answers. :-)

Comment: @Gaj This function is better for me because I want to pass in multiple boolean values into a cursor. I just pass in 1 or 0 directly from the function and that makes my code cleaner.