# PLSQL - Comparison operator in select

Tags: plsql, operator-keyword

How can i use a comparison operaton in a select
i.e.

> select 1=2 from dual;

Expecting a boolean result

This request give me an error
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use BOOLEAN type in SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465405/how-to-use-boolean-type-in-select-statement)

Comment: no, I can't add functions nor can I use case

Comment: _I can't add functions nor can I use case_, why? What can you use? And what you expecting as a boolean result - a string 'FALSE' or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the comparison operators but in the clauses where a boolean value is expected, e.g. `WHERE`, `HAVING` etc.

An reprodicible example without using the functions and `case` operator:

```
select (
    select 'true'  from dual where 1=2 union all
    select 'false' from dual
    order by 1 desc fetch first row only) "boolresult"
from dual
/

boolresult
----------------
false
```